# RestKit crash while trying to map object

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

This is the crash log:

```
2014-06-24 10:46:34.725 [30190:f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CropTypes 0x162638> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key crops.'
```

I have those 3 classes:

```
@interface CropTypes : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) ErrorStatus *errorStatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *crops;

@end

@interface ErrorStatus : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *errorCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *errorMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *success;

@end

@interface Crop : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *idNum;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;

@end
```

This is the JSON response:

```
{
  ErrorStatus: {
    ErrorCode: 0,
    ErrorMessage: null,
    Success: true
  },
  CropTypes: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    },
    {
      Id: 4,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    },
    {
      Id: 5,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    },
    {
      Id: 6,
      Name: "NUM",
      Url: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I map the objects:

```
- (void)initRoutes
{
    RKRequestMethod method = RKRequestMethodGET;

    RKRoute *cropTypeRoutes = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[CropTypes class] pathPattern:@"GetCropType" method:method];
    cropTypeRoutes.shouldEscapePath = YES;
    [self.manager.router.routeSet addRoute:cropTypeRoutes];
}

- (void)initMappingObjectsAndDiscriptors
{
    RKRequestMethod method = RKRequestMethodGET;

    RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ErrorStatus class]];
    [errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"ErrorCode" : @"errorCode", @"ErrorMessage" : @"errorMessage", @"Success" : @"success" }];

    //          Corp type service
    //
    RKObjectMapping *cropItemMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Crop class]];
    [cropItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Id" : @"idNum", @"Name" : @"name", @"Url" : @"url" }];

    RKObjectMapping *cropTypesMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CropTypes class]];
    [cropTypesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"CropTypes" toKeyPath:@"crops" withMapping:cropItemMapping]];
    [cropTypesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"ErrorStatus" toKeyPath:@"errorStatus" withMapping:errorMapping]];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:cropTypesMapping
                                                                                                        method:method
                                                                                                   pathPattern:@"GetCropType"
                                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
}
```

What seems to be the problem? This is maybe the 100 time that I'm using RestKit and nothing is changed from previous times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in the .m for `CropTypes`? Cleaned and rebuilt? The code looks fine so I'm guessing it's a build or other code issue with `CropTypes`...

Comment: addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary is of the format {"MappingObjectkey":"JSONvalue"} noting but `[cropItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Id" : @"idNum", @"Name" : @"name", @"Url" : @"url" }];` Will change to `[cropItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"idNum" : @"Id", @"name" : @"Name", @"url" : @"Url" }];` Change the same manner in all other places.